# How to flip all the bits in Java BitSet while preserving its length

Tags: java, bit, bitset

How can I flip all the bits in a Java [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html), while preserving its length?

For example, given the following BitSet:

```
BitSet.valueOf(new byte[] { 0b100111 })
// {0, 1, 2, 5}
```

Is there a simple method to flip all the bits, while preserving the BitSet length (6, in the above example)?

I would like to get:

```
BitSet.valueOf(new byte[] { 0b011000 })
// { 3, 4 }
```

Comment: There is a flip function in Java Bitset: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#flip(int,%20int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitSet` has a [`flip(from, to)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#flip(int,int)), which allows you to flip bits in a range:

```
yourBitSet.flip(0, length);
```

The question you need to answer, however, is what you actually mean by "length".

- A `BitSet` has the [`size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#size()) method, but that reports the number of bits it has allocated space for - perhaps more than you think the size is.
- It also has a [`length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#length()) method, which reports the highest-set bit in the bit set - perhaps less than you think the length of the bitset is.

Assuming you're OK with using `length()`, you can use:

```
yourBitSet.flip(0, yourBitSet.length());
```

Of course, since this clears the highest-set bit, `yourBitSet` will have a smaller `length()` afterwards.